# Close Dropdown if click outside - NO ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm developing a dynamic project which has multiple dropdown-buttons, and they can't have IDs because their quantity is not static. I made a function that works to open - close them by doing click on each button, but if you click outside of them they don't close, which is necessary. I tried with this function but it didn't work, and I can't use a function with ID's by their dynamic quantity. I hope you could help me. Thank you!!

***The failed JS function***

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (!event.target.matches('dropdown-list')) {

    var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-button");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
        var x = dropdown[i];
        if (x.classList.contains('show')) {
            x.classList.remove('show');
        } 
    }

}}
```

The rest of my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

    <style>     
        a {
            outline: 0;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .dropdown{
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        display: flex;
        margin-left: 3px;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding-top: 2px;
        }
        .dropdown-button{
        height: 34px;
        width: 34px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        justify-content: center;
        }
        .active.dropdown-button{
        background-color: lightgrey;
        }

        .dropdown-dropdown{
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 50%;
        }
        .dropdown-list {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        width: auto;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 18;
        right: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        }
        .dropdown-list.show{
        display: inline-flex;
        }

        .dropdown-a {
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        color: black;
        padding: 8px 20px 8px 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-size: 15px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        }
    </style>

</head>


<body>  
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-button" onclick="OpenCloseDropdown(this);">
            X
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-list">
            <a href="" class="dropdown-a">
            123</a>
            <a href="" class="dropdown-a">
            ABCD</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-button" onclick="OpenCloseDropdown(this);">
            Y
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-list">
            <a href="" class="dropdown-a">
            123</a>
            <a href="" class="dropdown-a">
            ABCD</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-button" onclick="OpenCloseDropdown(this);">
            Z
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-list">
            <a href="" class="dropdown-a">
            123</a>
            <a href="" class="dropdown-a">
            ABCD</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
function OpenCloseDropdown(e) {
    var x = e.parentNode.querySelector('.dropdown-list');
    if (x.classList.contains('show')) {
        x.classList.remove('show');
        e.classList = 'dropdown-button';
    } else {
        x.classList += " show";
        e.classList = 'dropdown-button active';
    }    
}
```

I have two kinds of clicks: the first kind is clicking on a button, in which case that button will toggle the show. The second kind is clicking outside all buttons.

Comment: So, you have two kinds of clicks: the first kind is clicking on a button, in which case that button will toggle the show. The second kind is clicking outside all buttons. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes sir, the first kind of click is on a button but if the user clicks outside, the second kind of click, the dropdown of the button "active" closes immediately.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle where only the Javascript you need is missing? When running your HTML, I can only see X, Y and Z, but have no clue what the dropdowns are and how should they work.

Comment: Not sure if it might be the issue but you should add classes to the classList using the add() method. What I think happens is you overwrite the classList API with a simple string. Even better would be to use toggle('show'), which handles all the logic in your if/else statement. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList for more information